# How to get Apache Kafka metrics in JSON format

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, health-monitoring

I'm trying to get Apache Kafka health metrics such as Broker, Producer, Consumer, Zookeeper, Topics, etc. metrics without using Confluent or any other software/plugin.

I need to expose these and store them in Elasticsearch. So far not able to extract this info. Any pointers on how I can extract this information from a running Apache Kafka docker container?

Comment: I think this post might help you:
https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/collecting-kafka-performance-metrics/

.Kafka exposes its metrics through JMX. You can read data and move them to your Elasticsearch. Maybe you can find a beat plugin that exports this JMX data.

Comment: Thanks, Seyed. Will try that this.

Comment: You're welcome. Also I published an article about monitoring Kafka using JMX. You can view it at https://medium.com/@mousavi310/monitor-apache-kafka-using-grafana-and-prometheus-873c7a0005e2

Answer (score 1):

As @Seyed Morteza Mousavi says, the metrics are exposed through JMX.

You're going to need additional software/plugin to get the data though. If you're using Elasticsearch then within the same stack is [Beats](https://www.elastic.co/blog/brewing-in-beats-add-support-for-jolokia-lmx) which can stream JMX metrics to Elasticsearch directly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.